# NextJs - next.config.js - CSS loader + custom Webpack config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I'm working with NextJS and I'm trying to custom my configuration. So far, I have tried to add CSS support + files support.

Here my next.config.js :

```
const webpack = require("webpack");  
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');


module.exports = withCSS({

  webpack : (config, { dev }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
            test: [/\.svg$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "public/media/[name].[ext]",
              publicPath: url => url.replace(/public/, "")
            }
          });
    return config;
  } 
})
```

my console returns me :

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use
>   Chunks.addGroup instead

I can't figure out what fails.

If anybody have an hint, would be great,

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried wrapping it in other ways?
This might work (not 100%):

```
module.exports = (config, { dev }) =>{
config.module.rules.push({
        test: [/\.svg$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "public/media/[name].[ext]",
          publicPath: url => url.replace(/public/, "")
        }
      });
return withCss(config);
```

} 
}

Also there is a withImages wrapper, https://github.com/twopluszero/next-images

```
const withImages = require('next-images') 
module.exports = withImages(withCss())
```